# How can I write WiX XSLT which merges components

Tags: xslt, wix

I have a .wxs file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <Directory>
            <Directory Id="d1">
                <Component Id="c1" ...>
                    <File Id="f1" KeyPath="yes" ... />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="c2" ...>
                    <File Id="f2" KeyPath="yes" ... />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="c3" ...>
                    <File Id="f3" KeyPath="yes" ... />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
            <Directory>
                <Component>
                ...
            </Directory>
            ...
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="cg1">
            <ComponentRef Id="c1" />
            <ComponentRef Id="c2" />
            <ComponentRef Id="c3" />
            ...
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I want to 'merge' components above, i.e., I want to move files f2, f3 into component c1 and want to remove compoents c2, c3, plus component refs of c2, c3. In my actual source code there are much more directories including components. My intention is to reduce the number of components, i.e., for any pattern like

```
<Directory>
    <Component>
        <File KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component>
        <File KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    ...
    <Component>
        <File KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

I want to reduce them into just one component(maybe the first component) including many files, like:

```
<Directory>
    <Component>
        <File KeyPath="yes" />
        <File />
        ...
        <File />
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

I know it's not recommemded to include many files in one component, but I want to do that to reduce the uninstallation time. Now, my installer takes pretty long time to uninstall and I assume it's because it has too many components(20,000 or so).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to achieve that is to use the `following-sibling` axis:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wi:Directory">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Only apply the first <Component> element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="wi:Component[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wi:Component[1]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Apply attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- Apply the <File> element in this <Component> element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="wi:File"/>
      <!-- Apply the <File> elements in all following <Component> siblings -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::wi:Component/wi:File"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="d1">
      <Component Id="c1">
        <File Id="f1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="c2">
        <File Id="f2" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="c3">
        <File Id="f3" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="cg1">
      <ComponentRef Id="c1"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="c2"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="c3"/>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <Directory>
      <Component Id="c1">
        <File Id="f1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <File Id="f2" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <File Id="f3" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="cg1">
      <ComponentRef Id="c1"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="c2"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="c3"/>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Note that you'll have to deal with orphaned `ComponentRef` elements, which should also be removed in order to avoid WiX compiler complain

Comment: @YanSklyarenko: Thanks for pointing that out! I'm not familiar with WiX. To remove the orphaned `<ComponentRef>` elements, you can simply add `<xsl:template match="wi:ComponentRef"/>` into the stylesheet. Or is it necessary to remove the entire `<Fragment>` or `<ComponentGroup>` element?

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. Thank you Eero Helenius.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
            exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kRemoveComps" 
             match="wix:Directory/wix:Component[position()&gt;1]" use="@Id" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wix:Directory" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wix:Component[1]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Attr. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <!-- File in this Component -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wix:File" />

            <!-- Files in siblings -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../wix:Component[position()&gt;1]/wix:File" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[position()&gt;1]/wix:File">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Removing KeyPath Attr. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='KeyPath')]|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Removing ComponentRef -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('kRemoveComps', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```